# AngularJS: Reassigning an object vs. replacing it in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a subscriber/observer pattern for displaying data in realtime for my angular app.

The observer is built with a factory injected into the angular controller and whose role is to fetch data and update it. The basic code structure can he found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrager/67QR7/3/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('MyFactory', [function () {

    var Collection = {};
    Collection.isLoaded = 0;
    Collection.data = [1, 2];
    Collection.username = "corey and eric";
    Collection.update = function () {
        Collection.data.push(new Date())
    }
    Collection.replace = function () {
        // If you do Collection.data = []
        // here you are doing the same thing
        // as the empty collection bug.  I can't
        // tell you EXACTLY why this confuses angular
        // but I'm 99% sure it's the same phenomenon
        Collection.data = [new Date()]
    }
    Collection.replace_fixed = function () {
        // This works
        Collection.data.length = 0
        Collection.data.push(new Date())
    }
    return Collection;

}])


function MyCtrl($scope, MyFactory) {
    $scope.name = 'Eric';
    $scope.items = MyFactory.data;
    $scope.replace = function(){
        console.log("replace")
        MyFactory.replace()
        //$scope.items = MyFactor.data;
    }
    $scope.replace_fixed = function(){
        console.log("replace_fixed")
        MyFactory.replace_fixed()
        //$scope.items = MyFactor.data;
    }
    $scope.update = function(){
        console.log("update")
        MyFactory.update()
    }
}
```

The factory (MyFactory) contains a collection (Collection.data). Any push (/splice) to that collection is reflected in the scope, but if I replace the entire collection (Collection.replace()) the change is no longer reflected in $scope. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/67QR7/4/

changed the thing stored on scope to be the factory instead of data. then the html repeat to do `items.data`.

So it looks like this is because you replaced the reference inside collection, but that doesn't change where `$scope.items` was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

So you are creating a reference to `MyFactory.data` from `$scope.items`. Angular puts a `$watch` on `$scope.items` and looks for changes. When you call `MyFactory.replace`, you change `MyFactory.data`, but `$scope.items` remains the same. So as far as your watch is concerned, nothing has happened.

You can fix this by using `replace_fixed`, or watch for changes to `MyFactory.data`. http://jsfiddle.net/KtB93/

```
    $scope.MyFactory = MyFactory;

    $scope.$watch("MyFactory.data", function(newData) {
        console.log('myFactory.data changed');
        $scope.items = newData;
    });
```

Or alternatively (probably better), you can use a function as the watch expression so you don't have to plop `MyFactory` on the scope (http://jsfiddle.net/XAW54/1/):

```
  $scope.$watch(function() {
        return MyFactory.data;
    }, function(newData) {
        $scope.items = newData;
    });
```